# Get form data using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to get form data using ajax but I can't get the values.

I have this javascript code to call the ajax function :

```
$( "#form_scenario_eco" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Pour éviter que la page se reload
        var formData = ($('#form_scenario_eco').serializeArray());
        $.post("/kohana-v3.3.5/ajax/nouveau_scenario_eco",{scenario_eco : formData}, function(data){
            alert(data);
        }, 'json');
    });
```

In my ajax file, I get the form data with :

```
 $scenario = $_POST['scenario_eco'];
```

With Chrome, I have an error 500 (Internal Server Error) because I can't get the `$_POST['scenario_eco']`.

Can someone tell me how should I get these data please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the cause of your 500 (Internal Server Error) by checking your error logs. You won't be able to retrieve the form data until the error is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

HTML

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("form.php",{ data: $(this).serializeArray() }).done(function(data){
            alert(data);
        })
    });
```

PHP

```
var_dump($_POST['data']);
```

Be sure that your inputs marked with 'name' attribute